# Select certain columns based on multiple criteria in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset:

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5],
                      'type':['corp','smb','smb','corp','mid'],
                      'sales':[34567,2190,1870,22000,10000],
                      'sales_roi':[.10,.21,.22,.15,.16],
                      'sales_pct':[.38,.05,.08,.30,.20],
                      'sales_ln':[4.2,2.1,2.0,4.1,4],
                      'cost_pct':[22000,1000,900,14000,5000],
                      'flag':[0,1,0,1,1],
                      'gibberish':['bla','ble','bla','ble','bla'],
                      'tech':['lnx','mst','mst','lnx','mc']})
my_df['type'] = pd.Categorical(my_df.type)
my_df
    id  type    sales   sales_roi   sales_pct   sales_ln    cost_pct    flag    gibberish   tech
0   1   corp    34567   0.10        0.38        4.2         22000       0       bla         lnx
1   2   smb     2190    0.21        0.05        2.1         1000        1       ble         mst
2   3   smb     1870    0.22        0.08        2.0         900         0       bla         mst
3   4   corp    22000   0.15        0.30        4.1         14000       1       ble         lnx
4   5   mid     10000   0.16        0.20        4.0         5000        1       bla         mc
```

And I want to filter out all variables who end in "_pct" or "_ln" or are equal to "gibberish" or "tech". This is what I have tried:

```
df_selected = df.loc[:, ~my_df.columns.str.endswith('_pct') &
~my_df.columns.str.endswith('_ln') &
~my_df.columns.str.contains('gibberish','tech')]
```

But it returns me  an unwanted column ("tech"):

```
    id  type    sales   sales_roi   flag    tech
0   1   corp    34567   0.10        0       lnx
1   2   smb     2190    0.21        1       mst
2   3   smb     1870    0.22        0       mst
3   4   corp    22000   0.15        1       lnx
4   5   mid     10000   0.16        1       mc
```

This is the expected result:

```
    id  type    sales   sales_roi   flag
0   1   corp    34567   0.10        0   
1   2   smb     2190    0.21        1   
2   3   smb     1870    0.22        0    
3   4   corp    22000   0.15        1   
4   5   mid     10000   0.16        1
```

Please consider that I have to deal with hundreds of variables and this is just an example of what I need.

Comment: `colums` is spelled wrong should be `columns`

Comment: Corrected the error in the question. Thank you @It_is_Chris

Comment: `my_df[my_df.columns[~my_df.columns.str.endswith(('_pct','_ln','gibberish','tech'))]]` Put all the `endswith` in a single tuple

Comment: So I needed double parenthesis. Thank you very much @It_is_Chris, how can I award your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, what you are doing will return every column because of how the conditions are written. `endswith` will accept tuples so just put all the columns you are looking for in a single tuple and then filter

```
my_df[my_df.columns[~my_df.columns.str.endswith(('_pct','_ln','gibberish','tech'))]]

   id  type  sales  sales_roi  flag
0   1  corp  34567       0.10     0
1   2   smb   2190       0.21     1
2   3   smb   1870       0.22     0
3   4  corp  22000       0.15     1
4   5   mid  10000       0.16     1
```

Comment: Now I see you didn't used `loc`. Anyway, it works fine. Just a question, I tried this: `df_selected = my_df.loc[:, ~my_df.columns.str.endswith('_pct') & ~ my_df.columns.str.endswith('_ln') & ~ my_df.columns.str.contains(('gibberish','tech'))]`but it returned me an error. It wasn't just a double parenthesis as I wrongly assumed. Why my attempt couldn't work?

Comment: The issue is with this line `my_df.columns.str.contains(('gibberish','tech'))` `string.contains` does not accept `tuples` but `string.endswith` does that is the difference.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and great answer @It_is_Chris. Now I understood this. Have a great day

Comment: You're welcome. Also, just so you are aware, `string.contains` does accept the `|` operator so `my_df.columns.str.contains('gibberish|tech')` will work as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
criterion = ["_pct", "_ln", "gibberish", "tech"]

for column in my_df:
    for criteria in criterion:
        if criteria in column:
            my_df = my_df.drop(column, axis=1)
```

Ofcourse you can change the if statement in line 3 to endswith or something of your choice.

Comment: Hi Pixelbog, thanks for the answer. Let me share my take: `df_selected = my_df.loc[:, ~my_df.columns.str.endswith('_pct') & ~ my_df.columns.str.endswith('_ln') & ~ my_df.columns.str.contains('gibberish|tech')]`. With contains you can specify this or that word... anyway the answer from It_is_Chris is simpler than mine.

Comment: Hello Alexis. Great solution! Yeah I am quiet new to pandas and never would had thought of doing this that way, but great that I learned something new :)